# How can I stop other text moving down on my Nav bar on hover?

Tags: html, css, navbar

I'm trying to make the text on my nav bar grow in size on hover, I've managed to do this but when I do this the other text links move down slightly and push the others to the right (except the end one)

here's my code:

```
/* -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

html, body {
margin:0;
padding:0;

}

.header {
margin-top:-7px;
background-color:#333333; 
height:70px;
}

.container {
 max-width: 940px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 30px 10px;
}

.nav {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0px 0;
color:white;
}

.nav li {
color: #fff;
display: inline;
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 15px;
margin-right: 25px;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
 -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s ease;
transition: all 0.5s ease;
} 


/* NAV PROPERTIES */

.nav li:hover{
cursor: pointer;
font-size:18px;
text-shadow:0px 0px 5px white;
margin-top: 10px; 
padding: 6px;
}
```

Comment: What is your navigation bar HTML code?

Comment: please make a sample or use https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/gnd6q0sp/

Answer (score 0):

Define a line-height on `.nav li`

```
.nav li {
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gnd6q0sp/1/

Comment: Doesn't stop the other list items moving.

Comment: Thank you! That's stopped the text moving down, any way of stopping it moving to the right?

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the size and margins of the list items...of course the other links move...that's what is supposed to happen.

One option is to just visually scale the list item using a transform instead.

```
.nav li:hover{
    transform:scale(1.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    text-shadow:0px 0px 5px white;
}
```

[**JSfiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/gnd6q0sp/2/)

**Note: I am not recommending this option, I think there are better methods available to you.**